# ModuleNotFoundError when launching script from terminal but not in interpreter

Tags: python, package

I am having the error shown in title.
The context is this:

- MainDir

  - PackageDir

    - `__init__.py`
    - `otherpython.py`
  - ScriptDir

    - `script.py` (which imports Package)

If I go in a terminal while in MainDir and run `python ScriptDir/script.py` I get the error in the title, that is that my package is not found.
If, however, I open a python interpreter from the MainDir, and then import the package, the package is found without issues.

```
MainDir > python
>>> import Package     #No problems
```

Note that `PYTHONPATH` contains the PackageDir. When checking the `sys.path`, the output contains the absolute path to the `PackageDir`, that is

```
sys.path = ['/home/user/MainDir/PackageDir','PathToAnaconda',...]
```

is part of the outputed list.

I am very confused what is going on here, could anyone help me?
Thank you

Comment: What is package here ?  Is it some file inside PackageDir ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming by `import package` you are trying to access something from `PackageDir`

Can you try this in your `script.py`

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/MainDir/PackageDir")
```

Someone asked something similar in the below link.

Here is a clear answer for the same [importing-files-from-different-folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder/4383597#4383597)

Comment: It does work, but there's something I don't get. That command adds the relative path to the sys.path (/MainDir/PackageDir), but I already have the absolute version of the path in it (/home/user/MainDir/PackageDir). Why would I need to have the relative too? Is python that bad at managing packages?

Comment: can you show how absolute version of path is mentioned  in your case?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer, let me know if that helps